# Cannot access a disposed object; Object name: 'RichTextBox'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox

im creating a label that counts a line and column of a richtextbox using this code:

```
int line = 1 + richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine());
int column = 1 + richTextBox1.SelectionStart - richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
label1.Text = "line: " + line.ToString() + ", column: " + column.ToString();
```

inside:

```
public void timercountline_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

but everytime i close the form but i leave a text in richtextbox or i input text in richtextbox then delete it all this error:

```
Cannot access a disposed object; Object name: 'RichTextBox'
```

appears pointing to the 1stline of the code which is:

```
int line = 1 + rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(rtb.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine());
```

anyone knows how can i avoid it? thanks a lot! really in need .

Comment: i try to comment the 1stline and now 2ndline got the error -_- what should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved -_-

i just try to transfer all codes in TextChangedEvent and it worked fine now .

thanks and sorry for inconvenience .

Comment: but still i will still be glad if i know the real answer to this :P thanks .